# How to calculate elapsed time between two HTTP samplers in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I tried to calculate elapsed time as follows. I added the code in Beanshell Post Processor something like this (with courtesy of another thread in StackOverflow).

**For the sampler1**

```
 long request1 = prev.getTime();
    vars.put("sampler1", String.valueOf(request1));
```

**And in sampler 2 I added** .

```
long request2 = prev.getTime();
vars.put("sampler2", String.valueOf(request2));
long request1 = Long.parseLong(vars.get("sampler1")); 
long request2 = Long.parseLong(vars.get("sampler2"));
long delta = (request1 - request2); // calculate difference
log.info("Time difference is: " + delta + " ms");
```

**And the same delta is captured in .csv file as follows.**

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("delta.csv", true);
out.write((String.valueOf(delta)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush();
out.close();
```

I do get the values in the **CSV file in a single row**.

But I'm looking for a way to capture these values using sample variables and map it to other sample variables that I'm capturing in another CSV file.

I appreciate if someone can provide a way to do this.

Comment: sorry I gave 4 spaces to add code in my question, but not sure why it is not taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing variable to another CSV file using Beanshell go for [Sampler Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property instead.

1. Add the next line to the end of 2nd PostProcessor:

   ```
   vars.put("delta", String.valueOf(delta));
   ```
2. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   sample_variables=delta
   ```

On next JMeter restart you will see a new column having "delta" variable value in .jtl results file.

Another approach of setting Sample Variables property is passing it via -J command line argument as:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=delta,somethingelse -n -t testplan.jmx -l results.jtl
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information using, setting and overriding this and other JMeter properties.

You can also use [Flexible File Writer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) for that (you will still need Sample Variables).

Comment: Thank you! Great tip! I'm able to get all the values as expected, but if I use the same results.jtl file and upload it to PerfMon listener I can not see the graph because I do see some failures in results.jtl file. The same can be be uploaded to other listeners fine. Is there any way to get PerfMon listener in non-GUI mode separately but still keep the results.jtl file for other listeners.

Comment: Yes, I found the way to save PerfMon results into a different file by just pointing to new file in browse text box. Thanks